# AWS ELB rewrite http to https

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I am using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.  I would like to rewrite all `http` traffic to `https`.

I have the following configuration:

[image]

But if I try change the `Instance Protocol` of either of the above two to `https (443)`, then when I try access my site, it just hangs.

**Question**

How do I configure AWS Elastic Beanstalk to rewrite all `http` traffic to `https`?

Comment: Its not possible to redirect http to https from load balancer. You need to do it from the webserver in ec2 or from a AWS CloudFront if you place CF infront of load balancer

Comment: @Ashan you can terminate client side https at elb and communicate with your backend app over http: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-load-balancer-support-for-ssl-termination/

Comment: SSL termination is possible, i was referening to redirect the browser url from http to https

Comment: agreed, however from OP's screenshot it looks like they're just doing clientside https, going to backend over http. OP, please clarify your question.